# ; as a new modifier key

Tags: autohotkey, modifier-key

**I want `;` to be a new modifier key.** The following works almost perfectly.

```
`;::
if GetKeyState("LShift", "P")
    Send `:
else
    Send `;
return

`; & x::
if GetKeyState("LShift", "P")
    ...
else
    ...
return
```

Only point 2. of the following wishlist does not work. Does anybody know how to fix this code?

1. `;` to be `;` when pressed alone
2. `shift ;` to be `:` when pressed alone
3. `;` with `x` to be the second `...`
4. `shift` with `;` with `x` to be the first `...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works perfectly, but is ugly code due to code duplication. Maybe cleaner code is possible.

```
started := 0
LShift & `;::
if started = 0
    started := A_TickCount
return
`;::
if started = 0
    started := A_TickCount
return

LShift & `; Up::
if A_TickCount - started < 500
    Send `:
started = 0
return

`; Up::
if A_TickCount - started < 500
    Send `;
started = 0
return

`; & x::
started = 0 ; <==== !
if GetKeyState("LShift", "P")
    ...
else
    ...
return
```

The key `;` now works as modifier key whenever it is used in a combination with `x` (without delay) or if it is pressed more than half a second. The delay is not neccesary and can be removed; it's just there prevent misinterpretation of an accidental modifier keypress as a `;`. The colon `:` works correctly too.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there are two possible ways to make point 2 work.

**Method 1:** keeps the *Left Shift* key's default behavior

**shift** + **;** results in **:** colon key being pressed. You can get point 2 to work by adding tilde "~" key before **`;** and removing

```
else 
    send `;
```

With ~ you can keep the key's default behavior. The new script will look something like this

```
~`;::
    if GetKeyState("LShift", "P") 
        Send `:
return 

`; & x::
    if GetKeyState("LShift", "P")
        ...
    else
        ...
return
```

By using this method script will be able to send **:** with **shift+;**.

**Method 2:** **removing** the *Left Shift* key's default behavior

Add the following snippet in your code

```
LShift::
    Send, {} 
return
```

This snippet will make the point 2 work but will render *Left Shift* key pretty much useless for everything else.

**EDIT**

**Method 3**: Making `;` wait for `x`

Adding `KeyWait` into the script will make it wait a certain amount of time before executing the code. Secondly using `Lshift` + `;` as an individual hotkey combination will output to `:`, removing the need for using `~` in return.

```
`;::
KeyWait, `;, T0.2
    Send `;
return

LShift & `;::
    Send `:
return 

`; & x::
KeyWait, `;, T0.2 
if GetKeyState("LShift", "P")
    ...
else
    ...
return
```

Comment: Thank you, but using method 1 a keypress of `;` immediately produces `;`, instead of waiting for a `x` to act as a modifier key, and using method 2, making the left shift key completely useless for other key combinations is not really an option.

Comment: Waiting is not really acceptable. Could you explain to me the assymetry between `;` and `:` in my original almost-solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2 ; allow 2 "instances" of the hotkey subroutine to exist simultaneously

`;::
If (A_PriorKey = "`;") ; ; was pressed alone
    Send `;
return

LShift & `;:: Send :

`; & x::
if GetKeyState("LShift", "P") ;  ; & LShift & x
    Send a
else                          ; ; & x
   Send b
return
```

Comment: Works for me.Could you test it with another keyboard? Some keyboards can't handle particular combinations of three keys, which is known as ["key jamming and ghosting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)).

Comment: Thank you for you explaination, but that is not the reason. I tested it with an external keyboard and had the same problem: if i first press and hold shift, and then press the `:` key, immediately a `:` will be typed. This is the original problem I had in my question. I can't explain why it doesn't happen to `;` without shift.